# Animating circles around button if it is clicked

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am trying to 
I have a button like this [before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC7Co.png)

i need to animate  circles around the button like this 
[after click[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN6lx.png)

```
       <Button
        android:id="@+id/tv_pasue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_player_pause" />
```

i have created drawable folder , it is ring so i am thinking to the ring will be same size of the button when the button clicked then i will animate changing the size of the ring but how to do it i dont know

here is my drawable file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" >

<gradient
    android:centerX=".6"
    android:centerY=".40"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gradientRadius="20"
    android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:type="radial" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<size
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="100dp" />

</shape>
```

i really don't know where to start 
i have searched for answers but not found what am looking for 
any help appreciated 
thanks

Comment: Use a FloatingAction Button instead, it has a ripple effect of its own else you can use a circular image and then do fade in/out animaiton on the circle. [Link to fade in fade out animation.](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/02/animate-fade-infade-out-by-changing.html)

Comment: I updated my question , i added  drawable folder , i think your suggestion "  can use a circular image and then do fade in/out animaiton on the circle" u meant the same right ?

Comment: Yes Kind of same thing.you will have to use Animation and anim folder for that.[Android Animation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/overview).